# Origin of "absurd"?

Tags: latin

As far as I can tell, the word absurd means "ridiculous." However, "ab-" means "not" or "away from" in Latin, while "surd" means "irrational". Thus, "absurd" literally translates to "not irrational", or "rational". Does anyone have any insight as to how the word suddenly came to mean the exact antonym?

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: What did Online Etymology Dictionary say?

Comment: OED says: [a. Fr. _absurde_, ad. L. _absurd-us_ inharmonious, tasteless, foolish, f. _ab-_ off, here intensive + _surdus_ deaf, inaudible, insufferable to the ear.]

Comment: @Joseph Farah What Lawler means is that the prefix _ab-_ is not privative (it doesn't change the meaning of the stem to its contrary) in this case. The _ab-_  works as an intensifier, it intensifies the meaning of 'surdus'. - If you are interested in questions like these, search the internet for good resources like those mentioned in the answer and comments to your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Lewis and Short's Latin Dictionary](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=absurdus&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059), "absurdus" literally means *out of tune*, and a figurative meaning of it is *irrational*, hence not in tune with your mind.